# Can't check if file permission attribute is read only using batch

Tags: batch-file, window

I am trying to count number of folders and files in a root directory using batch file.

The batch file counts number of

1. **OK Folders & Files** which are files or folders of which size is > 0 bytes,
2. **Denied Folders & Files** which are folders and files that can't be accessed, and
3. **Empty Folder & Files** which are folders and files that are empty.

The problem I am having is it is successfully giving the output for folders but in **files** case, the code is unable to detect denied files. Otherwise it's working fine.

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%x in (D:\Download\new.txt) do (

    for /D %%a in ("%%x") do (

        for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%i in ('dir /A /S "%%x\*" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "bytes"') do (
            if "%%j"=="File(s)" (
                set "numfiles=%%i"
            ) else (
                for /F %%a in ('dir /AD /B /S "%%x\*" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /C /V ""') do set "numfolders=%%a"
            )
        )

        set "size=0"

        for /f "tokens=3,5" %%b in ('dir /A /-C /S /W "%%~fa\*" 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /C:" "') do if "%%~c"=="" set "status=Unlocked" & set "size=%%~b"

        set /A size/=1024

        echo %%a,%%~nxa,!size!,%%~ta,!numfolders!,!numfiles!

        set "deniedFolderCount=0"
        set "okFolderCount=0"
        set "emptyFolderCount=0"

        set "deniedFileCount=0"
        set "okFileCount=0"
        set "emptyFileCount=0"

        for /F "delims=" %%m in ('dir /B /S "%%~fx\*"') do (

            for %%Z In ("%%m") do (

                if "%%~aZ" GEQ "d" (

                    set "size=0"
                    set "status=Locked"

                    for /F "tokens=3,5" %%b in ('dir /A /-C /S /W "%%~fm\*" 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /C:" "') do if "%%~c"=="" set "status=Unlocked" & set "size=%%~b"

                    set "data=0"

                    if !size! NEQ 0 set "data=Data"
                    if !size! == 0 if !status! == Unlocked set /A emptyFolderCount+=1
                    if !size! == 0 if !status! == Locked   set /A deniedFolderCount+=1
                    if !size! GTR 0 set /A okFolderCount+=1

                ) else (

                    REM Else starts here

                    set "size=0"
                    set "status=Locked"

                    for /F "tokens=3,5" %%b in ('dir /A /-C /S /W "%%~fm" 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /C:" "') do if "%%~c"=="" set "status=Unlocked" & set "size=%%~b"

                    set "data=0"

                    if !size! NEQ 0 set "data=Data"
                    if !size! == 0 if !status! == Unlocked set /A emptyFileCount+=1
                    if !size! == 0 if !status! == Locked   set /A deniedFileCount+=1
                    if !size! GTR 0 set /A okFileCount+=1
                )
            )
        )
        echo !deniedFolderCount!  !emptyFolderCount!  !okFolderCount!
        echo !deniedFileCount!  !emptyFileCount!  !okFileCount!
    )
)

endlocal
pause
```

**Note:** This batch file works just on English Windows because of `File(s)`.

Comment: where do you take `%%x` from?

Comment: @Stephan I have added complete code now.

Comment: @Compo Do you understand what the problem might be?

Comment: @Ebadkhan Please read [File and Folder Advanced Permissions](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-file-advanced.htm) and [How IT Works: NTFS Permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2005.11.howitworksntfs.aspx) and [How IT Works NTFS Permissions, Part 2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2006.01.howitworksntfs.aspx). With using just __DIR__ it is impossible to find out if a file can be read/executed as __DIR__ just runs folder queries. It would be necessary to try opening a file for reading to find out if user has permissions to read/execute a file.

Comment: @Ebadkhan *File can't be accessed* is not precise enough. It is possible to deny access to content of a file completely. It is possible to read/execute a file, but can't change its content. It is possible that a file can be read/executed and also data appended to the file, but it is not possible to overwrite this file completely, i.e. delete and create it new. It always depends on type of file access which file access is permitted or denied.